# How to customize fabricjs canvas coordinate system?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, fabricjs2

Is there any setting or something provided in fabricjs for customizing canvas coordinate system?

For my project I found easy to use cartesian coordinate system. Currently I am translating each object to `(width/2, height/2)` in order to move to cartesian coordinate system.

Left-top of canvas would be `(-width/2, -height/2)` instead of `(0,0)` as below image.

If any object with options `{left:0,top:0,originX:'center', originY:'center'}` is added to canvas, it should appear in the center not top-left corner

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything concerning viewport transform? Or do you need to be able to pan?
otherwise something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/epru5k46/4/) could help

Comment: Currently I am using exactly the way you suggested. But it still bothers cuz my canvas is zoomable, panable like small mapping. [here](https://github.com/mudin/indoorjs) is the github code with demo

Comment: Hmmm. I just used constants in our project to indicate the necessary offsets. not sure how else to fix it

Comment: Yeah I guess there is something we need to consider in version 2.x, it words for version 1.x

Comment: Good luck already!